# UI Changes in swift, CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, macos-sierra

I'm relatively new to swift and wondering if anyone could help with this issue.

I'm trying to make the label on a button change to a loading spinner during a service call, and then change to the response message of that call shortly after.

I get this error in my log:

`CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.`

Thanks for the help. I've read about these core animation errors, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as everything here is done asynchronously.

Here is the corrected code, thanks @Pierce:

```
        self.pastebinButton.isEnabled = false
        self.pastebinButton.title = ""
        self.pastebinProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

        pastebinAPI.postPasteRequest(urlEscapedContent: urlEscapeText(txt: text)) { pasteResponse in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pastebinProgressIndicator.stopAnimation(nil)
                if pasteResponse.isEmpty {
                    self.pastebinButton.title = "Error"
                } else {
                    self.pastebinButton.title = "Copied!"
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
                self.pastebinButton.title = "Pastebin"
                self.pastebinButton.isEnabled = true
            })
```

Comment: Is `pastebinProgressIndicator` a `UIProgressView`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is an `NSProgressIndicator`

Comment: I'm developing for mac OS

Comment: Is the completion block of `postPasteRequest()` called on the main thread?

Comment: I make this request using: `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {...`  where `request` is a `URLRequest`

Comment: Upon stepping through in the debugger, it looks like it occurs on a separate thread, I think.

Comment: I can post the code if it would help!

Comment: Please, that would help

Comment: Posted. Any advice is helpful, even not related specifically to this issue. Looking to learn!

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld - Try taking `self.pastebinProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)` and `self.pastebinButton.title = ""` outside of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block before you start the `postPasteRequest` I don't think that's necessary. Also when you update the `pastebinButton.title`, that should be inside of your `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` blocks.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld - you never want to update any UI on a background thread. Always include any UI code in your async

Comment: Oh thanks! I totally overlooked the "copied" and "error" changes. This is very helpful. Can you explain why the `start animation` and `title=""` changes don't need to be inside async, even though they are UI changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133159/discussion-between-pierce-and-alex-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're calling the `DispatchQueue.main.async` before you've even moved outside the main thread. This is unnecessary. Also once you're working on the background thread you are updating some UI (your button title) without dispatching back to the main thread. Never update UI on a background thread.

```
if !text.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {

    self.pastebinButton.title = ""
    self.pastebinProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

    pastebinAPI.postPasteRequest(urlEscapedContent: urlEscapeText(txt: text)) { pasteResponse in

       // Clean up your DispatchQueue blocks
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.pastebinProgressIndicator.stopAnimation(nil)
           if pasteResponse.isEmpty {
               self.pastebinButton.title = "Error"
           } else {
               self.pastebinButton.title = "Copied!"
           }
       }

       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
           self.pastebinButton.title = "Pastebin"
           self.pastebinButton.isEnabled = true
       })

    }
} else {
    Utility.playFunkSound()
}
```